# How to handle Ajax URL changes from a development to production environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The AJAX URLs used in my project change in different environments i.e. dev/test and production as shown below:

**dev/test:**

> http://localhost:60000/Users/GetAll

**production:**

> http://production.com/myProject/Users/GetAll

What would be the best way of tackling this?

My project is an MVC project but I will not use HTML Helpers to generate a URL as I don't want to mix C# with my JS script

Comment: ` I don't want to mix C# with my JS script.` Well sounds like you have an issue.... So if you can not use relative paths, somehow you need to know what the base path is for the environment....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Visual studio extension 
[Slow Cheetah](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah)
https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah

Actually this plugin changes the web.config file upon application publish. In your web.config you can store the 2 different API endpoints.

On your Dev Web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Endpoint" value="http://localhost:60000" />
</appSettings>
```

On Production

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Endpoint" value="http://production.com/myProject/" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you can get you endpoint like this

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Endpoint").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

So this value should come from server side, You define it in configs somewhere on server and based on which env is fired up ( Read conditional check based on env thread being executed) , you send that value/variable somehow down to the client app which can easily parse that information in app.js/whatever.js... ( start file of project) and make that a global variable for app from there on to use in your API calls. I haven't worked on C# but the approach has to be same.

Node.js gives this value in it's **process** as process.env. That simple!

You should really not hardcode this in client anywhere.